# Saving a figure without axes, legend or title in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using matlab to convert a signal into a spectrogram which I then save as a png image file.

This is what I currently have:[image]

I would like to only have the plot, no border, axes or legend.

(Bonus question: how to I get a greyscale spectrogram?)

Here is the code I use:

```
for index = 1:Nb_Samples
    %Loads the data from the current example
    Time_Data = Data4{1,index}.time;
    Signal_Data = Data4{1,index}.values;

    figure(1)

    %Generates the spectrogram for the current example
    spectrogram(Signal_Data,hamming(CustomHammingWindowSize1),CustomHammingWindowSize1/2,(PatchWindowSize^2-1)*2,1000,'yaxis')

    h=gcf;
    set(h,'PaperPositionMode','auto');
    set(h,'PaperOrientation','landscape');
    set(h,'Position',[20 20 1100 700]);
    print(gcf, '-dpng', 'Spectro.png')
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to directly save the data, without plotting it e.g. using `imwrite`, as anything you used to plot that must be a NxM matrix, i.e. an image. 
As @CrisLuengo says in the comments, just grab `spc=spectogram(...` the output, scale it to [0-1] and save it using `imwrite` for the best results.

I would not recommend it for this case, but you can always `colormap(gray)`, `axis off` and well, just not call `colorbar` (or `colorbar('off')`), to remove the extra stuff in the figure. But do good science! Save the data properly, don't introduce artifacts by adding the extra step of plotting.

Comment: Not sure I understand your second paragraph... I want to use greyscale with something like max intensity being black and minimum being white so I dont have to deal with 3 channels for information that could be encoded in only one.

I added the code I used if that changes anything.

Comment: @JSLavertu have you tried it? `colormap(gray)` should make a grayscale plot. You can learn how to define colormaps. You can also do `colormap(flipud(gray))` etc. Just try it. Also, when you add code, it has to be a [mcve]

Comment: @JSLavertu: `s=spectrogram(...)` returns the data in a matrix that you can save using `imwrite`. You will need to scale it first to the 0-1 range so data doesn't get clipped.